# What is the highest possible battery reaction voltage?

Tags: batteries, electrochemistry

For a battery cell with the overall chemical reaction $xA + R = A_xR$ (where x is the number of mols of A that reacts per mol of R), (Huggins 2008) defines the Maximum Theoretical Specific Energy (MTSE) as $(xE/W_t)F$ J/kg, where $E$ is the average voltage of the reaction, $W_t$ the sum of the molecular weights of the reactants engaged in the reaction, and $F$ is Faraday's constant. Clearly this can be boosted by finding low $W_t$ reactants (which is why lithium is popular). But what is the largest magnitude $E$ that can *in principle* be achieved?

In an open circuit $E= -\Delta G/zF$ where $\Delta G$ is the Gibbs free energy change of the reaction and $z$ the number of electrons transferred. So clearly we want a very high $\Delta G$, but it is not clear to me what the highest $\Delta G$ we can achieve. Even if there are high  $\Delta G$ reactions they are not necessarily of the right form of pushing electrochemistry (e.g. entalphy of formation of Al$_2$O$_3$ is -1582.3 kJ/mol, but aluminium oxidation doesn't look promising as a battery component). So presumably the actual bound on $E$ is going to depend on properties like electron negativity.

So, disregarding cost and practicality, can we say something like $E$ must be below $X$ volt because of the energy scale of electron transitions in molecules?

Comment: Rather than looking for the cell with the highest $E$, combine cells in series (into batteries) like everyone else does.

Comment: @Gert - Cells in a series doesn't change the MTSE.